# lmer errors and predict function in R v 3.6.1 / obtain confidence intervals from lmer model for a given independent variable

Tags: r, predict, lme4, mixed-models, confidence-interval

This is two questions in one, I hope this is OK.

First, I am trying to obtain confidence interval values from an `lmer` object from the `lme4` package. I've previously used R v 3.4.4 and the models run just fine, and I can find and display the confidence intervals for the mean fit on the plot. I've recently upgraded to R v 3.6.1, and am now getting an error message when using the `predict` function. I've shown this below as part of the code

My main question is, how do I calculate the upper and lower confidence limits for a given value? For  traditional `lm` I would use:

```
new.dat <- data.frame(variable = ##)
predict(lm_object, newdata = new.dat, interval = 'confidence')
```

But this doesn't work for `lmer` objects.

Here is the data:

```
TYPE <- c(rep("A", 100), rep("B", 31), rep("C", 18))
MAX<-c(NA,32.6,19.5,23.5,0,17.3,0,31,35.3,23.9,20.8,18.3,10.6,19.4,0,9,14.5,
       27.1,0,27.5,21,0,14.7,23.7,17.4,13.7,30.7,25.3,NA,0,16.5,0,NA,18.5,23.9,
       8.6,11.9,21.5,0,20.3,10.1,0,20.2,33.6,40.6,21.9,16.6,18.3,0,28.3,36.4,0,
       29.4,25.7,24.8,25,0,36.9,19,19.3,27.8,20.4,19.2,0,25.5,26.3,30.6,0,27.8,
       5.7,0,21,19.7,15.3,0,16.5,14.5,17.2,31.7,13,21.5,20,32.5,0,6.8,26.2,0,
       24.6,21.2,0,32.3,17.3,29.2,43.1,26.2,0,29.5,26.1,36.8,10.9,45.76,17.41,
       62.475,0,11.82,57.12,0,41.35,52.935,13.01,0,56.095,60.345,56.645,78.775,
       69.565,47.98,15.28,16.46,12.91,0,14.76,29.185,29.26,0,77.72,78.25,0,45.875,
       0,40.27,16.43,27.065,45.44,71.38,21.875,0,33.625,45.825,51.79,39.705,27.46,
       36.61,44.21,62.38,0,120.295,26.61,0)
STEM_PERCENT<-c(-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,0,-8.708496564,
                0,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,0,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,0,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,0,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,0,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,0,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,0,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,0,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,0,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,0,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,0,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,0,-8.708496564,-8.708496564,
                -8.708496564,-8.708496564,-7.541459043,0,-7.541459043,0,0,0,0,
                -7.541459043,-7.541459043,0,0,-7.541459043,-7.541459043,-7.541459043,
                -7.541459043,-7.541459043,0,-7.541459043,8.156584524,-7.541459043,0,
                0,8.156584524,-7.541459043,8.156584524,0,-7.541459043,0,-7.541459043,
                0,0,0,0,-7.541459043,-15.08291809,0,0,0,-7.541459043,-7.541459043,
                -8.156584524,8.156584524,0,0,-16.31316905,0,-16.31316905,0,8.156584524)
val<- data.frame(TYPE, MAX, STEM_PERCENT)
na.strings=c("",NA)
val<-subset(val,MAX!= "NA")
```

And here is the code which I use to run the mixed effects analysis, which works just fine in R v 3.4.4

```
library(lme4)
library(merTools)
mod3<-lmer(STEM_PERCENT~1+MAX+(1|TYPE)+(0+MAX|TYPE),data=val)
```

Here, I get the following error message, which I never received in R v 3.4.4

```
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.107451 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

code continues

```
mod4<-lmer(STEM_PERCENT~1+MAX+(1+MAX|TYPE),data=val) # also produces error not seen before


val2<-expand.grid(MAX=seq(0,120,length=1000),
                  TYPE=levels(val$TYPE))

val2$STEM_PERCENT<-predict(mod3,newdata=val2)

val3<-data.frame(MAX=seq(0,120,0.1))
val3$STEM_PERCENT<-predict(mod3,newdata=val3,re.form=~0)

CI <- cbind(val2, predictInterval(mod4, val2))


plot(val$MAX,val$STEM_PERCENT,pch=19,col=(1+as.integer((val$TYPE))),
     bty="l",cex=0.5,xaxt="n",las=1,ylim=c(-30,10),
     xlim=c(0,120),yaxt="n",xlab=NA,ylab=NA)

axis(side=2,tck=-0.02,at=seq(-30,10,10),cex.axis=0.5,
     font.axis=1,las=2,mgp=c(0,.5,0),labels=T)
axis(side=1,tck=-0.02,at=seq(0,120,20),
     cex.axis=0.5,labels=T,mgp=c(0,-0.1,0))


xv<-seq(0,120,0.01)
typea<-rep("A",length(xv))
yv<-predict(mod3,list(MAX=xv,TYPE=typea),type="response")
```

Here is where I get the error message in R v 3.6.1, which I don't get in v 3.4.4. The same is true of each instance of `yv`

```
Error in rep(0, nobs) : invalid 'times' argument
```

code continues

```
lines(xv,yv,col="red",lwd=1.5)

typeb<-rep("B",length(xv))
yv<-predict(mod3,list(MAX=xv,TYPE=typeb),type="response")
lines(xv,yv,col="green",lwd=1.5)

typec<-rep("C",length(xv))
yv<-predict(mod3,list(MAX=xv,TYPE=typec),type="response")
lines(xv,yv,col="blue",lwd=1.5)

lines(val3$MAX,val3$STEM_PERCENT,lwd=2)

ssmin<-smooth.spline(CI$MAX,CI$lwr,df=4)
lines(ssmin,lty=2,col="black",lwd=1)

ssmax<-smooth.spline(CI$MAX,CI$upr,df=4)
lines(ssmax,lty=2,col="black",lwd=1)
```

Which makes the following plot in R v 3.4.4 with no problems.

[image: LMER_OBJECT]

I'd like to be able to find upper and low confidence interval values around the mean at a given value of MAX, e.g. `upr` and `lwr` limits of the `fit` when MAX = 50. It looks like it should be somehwere around -2 and -12 for `upr` and `lwr` limits respectively. I'd also like to know what's going on with the error messages, which I've not previously received.

Any help and advice gratefully received, thanks

Comment: Relevant are most likely not the different R versions but the different versions of `lme4`.

Comment: The `newdata` parameter is documented to expect a data.frame and, indeed, `yv<-predict(mod3, data.frame(MAX=xv,TYPE=typea), type="response")` works just fine. If you haven't already, you should probably study `help("convergence")` regarding the "no convergence" warnings (which are not errors).

Comment: Thanks, @Roland. I solved the convergence problem by restarting the models with the parameter estimates before the algorithm failed to converge, thus:

`ss <- getME(mod3,c("theta","fixef"))

new_mod <- update(mod3,start=ss)`

For others, there is more help on the convergence problem [here](https://biologyforfun.wordpress.com/2018/04/09/help-i-have-convergence-warnings/)

Can you offer advice on the CI query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to determine CI values. Hopefully others may benefit from the solution. As usual, it was quite simple.

First, round the CIs to 0 d.p

```
CI$MAX<-as.numeric(round(CI$MAX,0))
```

Then, determine mean upper and lower values at MAX = 50

```
low<-mean(CI$lwr[which(CI$MAX==50)])
high<-mean(CI$upr[which(CI$MAX==50)])
```

Add lines to plot to check

```
abline(v = 50)
abline(h = low)
abline(h = high)
```

[image: lmer_solution]